# Error with php programing

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $StudentFirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $StudentLastName = $_POST['LastName'];
    $OrgID = $_POST['OrganizationId'];
    $AmountRaised = $_POST['AmountRaised'];
    $Captain = $_POST['Captain'];
}

$server = "mssql.up.ist.psu.edu";
$connectionInfo = array(
    'Database' => 'pjb5422',
    'UID' => 'sqlpjb5422',
    'PWD' => 'vIPY5De2',
    'Encrypt' => '0',
    'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8');
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);

if (!($connection)) {
    echo "Connection could not be established.";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {

    $query = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; //**BUILDING AN INSERT STATEMENT

    $var = array(rand(40, 100000000), $StudentFirstName, $StudentLastName, $OrgId, $AmountRaised, $Captain);

    $sendIt = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query, $var); //submit the query

    echo "<br>Thanks for Registering!!<br><br>Go <a href='MiniThon.html'>Home</a>";
}

?>
```

I get the following errors and it never submits to my SQL data base

> Notice: Undefined variable: StudentFirstName in \UP.IST.LOCAL\WEBSITES\pjb5422\AddDancer1.php on line 50
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: StudentLastName in \UP.IST.LOCAL\WEBSITES\pjb5422\AddDancer1.php on line 50
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: OrgId in \UP.IST.LOCAL\WEBSITES\pjb5422\AddDancer1.php on line 50
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: AmountRaised in \UP.IST.LOCAL\WEBSITES\pjb5422\AddDancer1.php on line 50
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Captain in \UP.IST.LOCAL\WEBSITES\pjb5422\AddDancer1.php on line 50

Comment: i recommend you change your title making it more specific to your question. form your tag and this website, it is obvious it is an error with php programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this line

```
 if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
```

to check other values that are required in your form since value doesn't have anything in it causing your declared variables to be null.

I also suggest that before executing your insert query you should first check if

> $StudentFirstName

and other variables are not empty before you execute the insert query.

```
else {
    if(!empty($StudentFirstName) && !empty($StudentLastName)){
         $query = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; //**BUILDING AN INSERT STATEMENT

         $var = array(rand(40,100000000),$StudentFirstName, $StudentLastName, $OrgId, $AmountRaised, $Captain);

         $sendIt = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query, $var); //submit the query

         echo "<br>Thanks for Registering!!<br><br>Go <a href='MiniThon.html'>Home</a>"; 
    }else{
      echo "Failed to insert record empty variables!";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything inside `if (isset($_POST['value'])) {` seems to not be executing.
You need to check that the $_POST['value'] value is actually set to something so the variables take on the required values.

Answer (score 0):

when `isset($_POST['value'])` return a `false`, your `$StudentFirstName` should be `Undefined variable` obbviously

```
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $StudentFirstName =$_POST['FirstName'];
    //...
}
```